# execlp() system call error in output

Tags: c, system-calls

This very simple example of `exec()` system call. Here, I am trying to call `execlp()` twice. But, I am not getting excepted output. It shows output only for first call with current directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() { 

        int ret1,ret2;
        ret1 = execlp( "pwd", "pwd", (char *) 0);
        ret2 = execlp( "date", "date", (char *) 0);
        return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
/home/aniket
```

Here, I can't see output for date. Can anyone please explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`execlp()`  *replaces* the current process image with a new process image.
It does *not return* (unless there was an error starting the new process).

Therefore the second `execlp()` call is never reached.

Answer (score 1):

`execlp ()` replaces the process that called it by the process which was called.

From [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) link:

"The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image."

To retain both the processes, use `fork().`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() { 

        int ret1,ret2;

        pid_t chd;
        chd=fork(); 
        if(chd==0)
        ret1 = execlp( "pwd", "pwd", (char *) 0);
        else if(chd>0)
        ret2 = execlp( "date", "date", (char *) 0);
        return 0;
}
```